# Tensor product of two spaces one of them is free module

Tags: abstract-algebra, free-modules

Let $V$ be a real vector space and let $S(V^*)$ be the symmetric algebra of $V^*$.
Suppose $L$ and $N$ are two $S(V^*)$-modules.

How to prove the statement in corollary 16 in the article by Kumar and Vergne on equivariant cohomology, which says that

> If $L$ is a free $S(V^*)$-module, then the tensor product space $L \otimes_{\mathbb R} N$ is also  free.

Comment: How are you defining the $S(V^*)$-module structure on the tensor product?

Comment: $L \otimes N$ is given a structure of $S(V^*)$-module by defining the action of an element $ f \in V^*$ to be $f.(m \otimes n)= fm \otimes n - m \otimes fn$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to **Lemma 15**, whenever you consider a tensor product of the form $S(V^*)\otimes N$ where $S(V^*)$ is the regular module, this is isomorphic to $S(V^*)\otimes N'$ where $N'$ has the trivial module structure. If $M$ is free, it is of the form $S(V^*)\otimes W$ and their argument in **Lemma 15** shows that $M\otimes N$ is isomorphic to $M\otimes N'$, which is ---unless I am missing something obvious--- free over $W\otimes N'$.

Comment: thank you so much @Pedro Tamaroff for your answer! I have two questions: why  If $M$ is free, then it is of the form $S(V^*)\otimes W$, what is W ?  and then I don't understand in the last when you said "$M \otimes N  $ is free over $ W \otimes N' $, don't we want it to be free over $\mathbb{R}$.? I have a little knowledge about properties of  modules , and I apology  if my questions are very stupid!

Comment: @asma That's the definition of a free module. Every module over the field $\mathbb R$ is free! This is crucially for modules over $S(V^*)$.

Comment: Please  @Pedro Tamaroff could you give me a brief proof or point me to a reference where I can find the proof of the claim " if M is a free $S(V^*)$-module, then it is of the form $S(V^*)\otimes W$". I'm stuck with this!

Comment: @asma That's the definition of a free module. You can consult any standard textbook on ring and module theory. :)

Comment: The definition of free module that I know is that it is a module generated by a set consisting of linearly independent elements.  I'm sorry to bother you but it would be very helpful if you suggest me a specific book that you know  wich contains the second definition.

Comment: @asma If $A$ is a $k$-algebra, and if $W$ is a free $A$-module generated by $f_1,\ldots,f_n$, then $W$ is isomorphic to $A\otimes_k V$ where $V$ is the $k$-module with basis those $f_i$. Can you see this? Maybe you're just not used to describing free modules using tensor products...

Comment: Thank you so much @Pedro Tamaroff for your reply! Actually, yes I'm not used to the description of free modules  you gave, I'll read more about them. Thanks again.